# Ffmpeg color opacity

Tags: colors, ffmpeg, opacity

I tried to rotate a video and keep the unused place due to the rotation transparent, to be able to overlay it later and to do that, I suppose that if the color was transparent is will be right; and in the official page (https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate) they said that you can give a color that ffmpeg would use in place of unused place due to the rotation of the video. So I tried, relatively to https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Color to put a color with these commands

> ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "rotate=PI/6:fillcolor=red@0.0" -acodec copy output.mp4

and

> ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "rotate=PI/6:fillcolor=red@0x00" -acodec copy output.mp4

And it doesn't work. The color remain opaque, and that whatever the value of the opacity (0.0 to 1.0)

Any of you can know what is happened?

Answer (score 0):

The filter output will generate the correct alpha, but since x264 - the encoder usually used with ffmpeg for H.264 - does not support alpha, the fill color shows up. You'll have to switch video codecs to preserve alpha

Something like,

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "rotate=PI/6:fillcolor=red@0.0" -c:v qtrle -acodec copy output.mov
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "rotate=PI/6:fillcolor=red@0.0" -c:v png -acodec copy output.mov
```

Comment: I tried your solutions. The qtrle format throws an error (I'm in windows) and the second didn't work. The color remain opaque :(

Comment: How are you testing the files?

Comment: To test files, I use some videos I have on my computer

Comment: How are you opening the files and testing opacity?

Comment: When I test the solution, I openned the video into VLC and see how it works. And all the times the opacity doesn't change at all :(. To do that I choose colors which are intense (like red or blue)

Comment: The commands I gave generate alpha which can be seen and used by apps like video editors (Premiere, Vegas) or compositors (After Effects..). What's your use case with a video player?

Comment: I want the space liberated by rotation to be tranparent because I want to overlay the video later with another. I try but when I overlay it didn't work. The color remain present

Comment: How are you going to overlay the video?

Comment: I will use the command ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex"[0:v][1:v] overlay=50:50:enable='between(t,10,15)'" -c:a copy output.mp4

Comment: Yes, I tried the one give by you, and it didn't work. :( I even tried to convert the mp4 file into a MOV one and it didn't work either :(

Comment: Run my PNG command with `-report` and also the overlay  and paste the contents of the generated logfiles.

Comment: ffmpeg started on 2016-01-19 at 17:32:27
Report written to "ffmpeg-20160119-173227.log"
Command line:
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "rotate=PI/6:fillcolor=red@0.0" -c:v png -report -acodec copy output.mp4
ffmpeg version N-76347-gdd36749 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme

Comment: The link is up, a dropbox one

Comment: The PNG has to be output to MOV as seen in the command. And please paste the results as code into your question.